# "oh no something has gone wrong" error on Kali Linux 2017.1 (Nvidia Drivers)

Tags: linux, nvidia-graphics-card, kali-linux, nvidia-geforce

I recently updated *Kali rolling to 2017.1* and fetched the latest kernel headers from the repo however after the upgrade I noticed that everything was fine except for **Nvidia** drivers not working(e.g. gpu not detected in hashcat). So I went ahead did some research on the matter and it turns out that **Nvidia** drivers don't work with newer Linux kernels(due to Realtime Preemption patches). So I decided to recompile the Linux kernel that I was on (version 4.9.25) from source and with success I managed to get the latest Nvidia drivers working, however I'm faced with one issue. I get the *"oh no something has gone wrong"* error with every boot. How do I get my login screen back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same problem.
After many hours of testing and googleing, I found XFCE as the only solution.
The problem seems to be not the NVIDIA driver, but Gnome3.
I tested Gnome3, LXDE and XFCE.
My hardware: Intel HD Graphics 5500 + NVIDIA GeForce 840M

```
apt-get install xfce4 xfce4-places-plugin xfce4-goodies
update-alternatives --config x-session-Manager
```

Then choose entry "/usr/bin/startxfce4"

For me it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try to login in recovery mode in GRUB, then just simply enter the root password and then enter. After that a terminal will open - then try:

```
apt-get purge nvidia-*
```

or

```
apt-get get remove nvidia-*
```

and then reboot.

Comment: apt-get purge nvidia-*

Comment: Problem is I need the Nvidia Drivers installed